# Get notifications from Inbox mobile app for reminders, but not emails?

Tags: gmail, notifications, inbox-by-gmail

This question applies to the Google Inbox mobile app.

I **do not** want notifications for random incoming emails as I'm trying to only check email twice a day.

I **do** want notifications for reminders, as I will usually set these for a specific time to remind myself of something.

Is there any way to do this? According to Inbox's settings, it looks like it's all or nothing.